# 'position-aware' aligning of sequences with letter annotations

Tags: python, r, bioinformatics, biopython, bioconductor

We have 2 DNA sequences (strings):

```
>1
ATGCAT
135198
>2
ATCAT
```

Expected output: first, we need to align these 2 strings, then get relevant annotation by index:

```
ATGCAT
AT-CAT
13-198
```

First part can be done using *Biostrings* package:

```
library(Biostrings)

p <- DNAString("ATCAT")
s <- DNAString("ATGCAT")
s_annot <- "135198"

x <- pairwiseAlignment(pattern = p, subject = s)

aligned(x)
# A DNAStringSet instance of length 1
#     width seq
# [1]     6 AT-CAT
as.character(x)
# [1] "AT-CAT"
as.matrix(x)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,] "A"  "T"  "-"  "C"  "A"  "T"
```

Current workaround for the 2nd part:

```
annot <- unlist(strsplit(s_annot, ""))
annot[ which(c(as.matrix(x)) == "-") ] <- "-"
# [1] "1" "3" "-" "1" "9" "8"
```

Works fine, but I was wondering if there is a *Biostrings* way of doing it (or any other packages), maybe by keeping the annotation in the *metadata* slot, then after aligning we get the matching annotation for matched bases in *metadata*, something like below:

```
getSlots("DNAString")
#      shared              offset              length     elementMetadata            metadata 
# "SharedRaw"           "integer"           "integer" "DataTable_OR_NULL"              "list" 

# just an idea, non-working code
s@metadata <- unlist(strsplit(s_annot , ""))
x <- pairwiseAlignment(pattern = p, subject = s)
metadata(x)
# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "3" "-" "1" "9" "8"
```

---

**Note:**

- With author's permission stolen from *BioStars* - https://www.biostars.org/p/415896/
- Author wanted *biopython* solution, so adding the tag, post *python* solution if possible, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from - https://www.biostars.org/p/415896/#9564298

---

This just popped up again in my inbox, so thought I'd come back with the solution I came up with.

I believe I arrived at the eventual solution based on an idea from Devon Ryan.

It's embedded in to a much more convoluted codebase, but the general idea was this:

1. Create a pairwise alignment of the sequences as normal.
2. Iterate through the alignment and create a sort of CIGAR string which captures the various sequence 'movements'.
3. Apply/map this same set of movements to the list of annotations corresponding to each position, thus repeating the set of operations

Code here:

https://github.com/jrjhealey/ISIS/blob/master/ImmunoRender.py#L35-L103

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
dna_fun <- function(s, p, a) {
  s <- strsplit(s, "")[[1]]
  p <- strsplit(p, "")[[1]]
  a <- strsplit(a, "")[[1]]
  ls <- length(s)
  lp <- length(p)

  r <- lapply(c(1,seq(lp)), function(x) {
    v <- rep(1, 5)
    v[x] <- 2
    v
  })

  mat <- sapply(r, rep, x = p)
  tfm <- mat == matrix(rep(s, ls), ncol = ls)
  m <- which.max(colSums(tfm))

  p2 <- mat[, m]
  p2[!tfm[,m]] <- "-"

  a[!tfm[,m]] <- "-"

  p2 <- paste(p2, collapse = "")
  a <- paste(a, collapse = "")

  return(list(p2, a))
}
```

with:

```
dna_fun(s1, s2, annot)
```

you get:

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "AT-CAT"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "13-198"
> ```

---

If you have corresponding vectors you can use `Map` together with the `dna_fun`-function:

```
s11 <- c("ATGCAT","ATCGAT")
s22 <- c("ATCAT","ATCAT")
annot2 <- c("135198","145892")

lm <- Map(dna_fun, s11, s22, annot2)

data.table::rbindlist(lm, idcol = "dna")
```

this gives:

> ```
>       dna     V1     V2
> 1: ATGCAT AT-CAT 13-198
> 2: ATCGAT ATC-AT 145-92
> ```

---

Data:

```
s1 <- "ATGCAT"
s2 <- "ATCAT"
annot <- "135198"
```

Answer (score 2):

As requested, a Biopython solution:

```
from Bio import Align

p = "ATCAT"
s = "ATGCAT"
s_annot = "135198"

aligner = Align.PairwiseAligner()
alignment = str(aligner.align(p, s)[0]).split()
middle = alignment.pop(1)
alignment.append("".join(c if m == "|" else m for c, m in zip(s_annot, middle)))

print("\n".join(alignment))
```

Output:

```
AT-CAT
ATGCAT
13-198
```